# is elvis operator with error handling safe for set default value?

Tags: php

in my code is usually use `if(!isset())` for set default value if the variable is empty
ex :

```
if(isset($_POST['noreg']))
{
 $noreg = $_POST['noreg'];
}
else
{
$noreg = 'empty';
}
```

my friend suggest me to use elvis operator with error handling, and it looks shorten than before,

```
$noreg = @$_POST['noreg'] ?: 'empty';
```

it works fine like my old code

but is it safe or it has any risk if i use it?

can anyone help me for this?
thanks

Comment: Shorter isn't necessarily better. Just stick with `$noreg = isset($_POST['noreg']) ? $_POST['noreg'] : 'empty';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` operator *suppresses error reporting*. That means there's still an error being produced, but it's being silenced. That's problematic for three reasons:

1. It's probably slower to raise and then discard an error than an `isset` check would be.
2. If you have a custom error handler, that handler may ignore `@` and still produce an error.
3. You have no idea what other kinds of errors you may be suppressing that you're not expecting.

Particularly, what if you accidentally write `@$_PSOT['noreg']`? PHP's error reporting won't be alerting you to this mistake and you're in the dark. If you'd use [`filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'noreg')`](http://php.net/filter_input) or `array_key_exists('noreg', $_POST)`, such mistakes could not be made.

<sub>(This example may be a bit contrived since `isset()` will suppress the same error, but it's to illustrate the pitfalls of using *error suppression* and why one must be very conscious of it.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you use it for simple variable initialization then it's ok. It will work on any expression & when preceding it, it will suppress the error.

Straight from documentation http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When
> prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be
> generated by that **`expression`** will be ignored.
>
> If you have set a custom error handler function with
> **`set_error_handler()`** then it will **still get called**, but this custom
> error handler can (and should) call error_reporting() which will
> return 0 when the call that triggered the error was preceded by an @.
>
> Currently the "@" error-control operator prefix will even disable
> error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script
> execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to
> suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available
> or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no
> indication as to why.

Comment: so nothing bad will happen if I keep using this?

Comment: @AKohar it depends on situation if you are using for simple purpose then it's ok.